# How to correlate (a changed-key-string passed to SCDynamicStoreCreate()'s callback) to a network device?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, system-configuration

My C/C++ program uses MacOS/X's SystemConfiguration function [SCDynamicsStoreCreate()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStore/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCDynamicStoreCreate) and friends to detect when the Mac's network configuration has changed, more or less as shown in the example code Apple provides [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn1145/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10002984-CH1-SECWHENGOODIPSGOBAD).

This works pretty well; in particular, the callback function I pass in as the third parameter to SCDynamicsStoreCreate() does get called whenever any of the Mac's network interfaces comes up or go down.

I'd like to refine things a little, though, by finding out exactly which interface(s) in particular have come up or gone down.  That way my program can be smart and only close sockets dependent on the now-departed network interfaces, instead of always recreating all sockets as it does currently.

Here's what my callback function looks like right now:

```
static void IPConfigChangedCallback(SCDynamicStoreRef /*store*/, CFArrayRef changedKeys, void * info)
{
   // Temporary debugging/exploratory code
   int c = CFArrayGetCount(changedKeys);
   for (int i=0; i<c; i++)
   {
      CFStringRef p = (CFStringRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(changedKeys, i);
      const char *cs = CFStringGetCStringPtr( p, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman ) ;
      printf("   key %i: [%s]\n", i, cs);
   }

   RecreateSocketsAndStuff();
}
```

When (as a simple test) I enable or disable the WiFi interface on my Mac, the above function gets called, and prints output like this:

```
    key 0: [State:/Network/Service/F0B25E8E-AAEF-45A1-A484-5D8F0C2BC061/IPv4]
```

I suspect that that long hexadecimal string corresponds to my Mac's Wi-Fi interface, but how do I map that value to my Mac's WiFi IP address (or MAC address, or interface index, or anything that I could use to correlate this callback to the data returned by [getaddrinfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to be interpreted relative to the [System Configuration Schema](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html).  As noted elsewhere in the [System Configuration Programming Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Components/SC_Components.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH207-CHDHFBBH):

> Although the schema is not private system API, it is very low level.
>   As much as possible, an application should avoid depending directly on
>   the schema and employ higher-level interfaces instead.

That said, you could pass the key to `SCDynamicStoreCopyValue()` to examine what that gives you.  I believe you get a dictionary of properties and their values.

You can also use the [`scutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scutil.8.html) command to explore the System Configuration store interactively.  For example, issue the `show` command with the key you got from your callback.  On my system, I get a dictionary showing subnet masks, the router, the interface name, and the IP addresses.